# glTexCoordPointer: meaning of u and v?

Tags: opengl

I use openctm to save 3d data. Here I can save texture coordinates.

The texture is later loaded this way:

```
const CTMfloat * texCoords = ctm.GetFloatArray(CTM_UV_MAP_1);
for(CTMuint i = 0; i < numVertices; ++ i)
{
  aMesh->mTexCoords[i].u = texCoords[i * 2];
  aMesh->mTexCoords[i].v = texCoords[i * 2 + 1];
}
```

texCoords is the float array (2 floats for one point). 
Later the texture is used this way:

```
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &aMesh->mTexCoords[0]);
```

My problem is that I need to generate the texCoords array. What does u and v mean? Is it the pixel position? Do I have to scale them by 1/255?

Comment: Don't use the deprecated fixed function pipeline! Makes your life and ours much easier.

Comment: I do not use these functions. The openctm demo viewer uses them. My part is to generate the texture map.

Comment: By the way: the texture itself is used with glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTexHandle);

Answer (score 0):

While not being related to programming, this tutorial gives a good introduction about *what* UV coordinates are: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/UV_Map_Basics

In general you don't "create" or "generate" the UV map programmatically. You have your 3D modeling artists create them as part of the modeling process.